# First occurence logic - power bi

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I have a table with data like below

```
Event name|  Event Id|     Acct Date |    Event Date 
Event1        1          2022-01-01    2022-01-01
Event1        2          2022-04-01    2022-01-01
Event1        3          2022-01-01    2022-01-01
Event1        4          2022-09-01    2022-01-01
Event2        1          2022-01-01    2022-01-01
Event2        2          2022-04-01    2022-01-01
Event2        3          2022-01-01    2022-01-01
Event2        4          2022-09-01    2022-01-01
```

Question:
I want to print a column saying Event Count with values 1 and 0

```
First Occurence,
If Acct Date = Event Date, then Event Count should be 1
Second Occurence, 
If Acct Date = Event Date, then Event Count should be 0
```

because we already have a match for the same event name and Acct Date = Event Date combination.

How do i achieve the above in power bi dax? Im new and any help would be greatly appreciated. tx

if(Acct Date = Event Date,1,0), this gives me event count as 1,0,1,0 , But what i need is 1,0,0,0. This should happen for every event name and Acct Date = Event Date combination.

Comment: How do you define: the first occurance? Please add some data to your table with Event2.

Comment: I have added event 2, so basically i need to print 1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0

Comment: You have to group the rows in the table by the Event Name column and make use of the COUNT function

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra column with the following DAX:

```
First Occurence = 
var EventName = 'Table'[Event name]
var EventId = 'Table'[Event Id]
var occurCount = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table'), FILTER('Table', 'Table'[Acct date] = 'Table'[Event Date] && EventName = 'Table'[Event name] && EventId > 'Table'[Event Id]))
return IF(ISBLANK(occurCount), 1, 0)
```

We run over the rows and for each row we are going to filter the table based on criteria. The criteria are based on Event name, Event Id and if the Acc Date = Event Date.

If you want to see what occurCount is ging you you cna peek by:

```
First Occurence = 
    var EventName = 'Table'[Event name]
    var EventId = 'Table'[Event Id]
    var occurCount = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table'), FILTER('Table', 'Table'[Acct date] = 'Table'[Event Date] && EventName = 'Table'[Event name] && EventId > 'Table'[Event Id]))
    return occurCount
```

Answer (score 0):

On whether your condition is met 1 is returned, else 0. The idea of the SWITCH is to embed multiple conditions which is a powerful to incorporate while working:

```
Event Count = SWITCH(TRUE(), COUNTROWS (TableName) > 1, 1, 0)
```